# Usage of closures with multiple arguments in swift

Tags: closures, swift

This question is largely based on this one:

[**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031084/closures-return-value-previously-completionblock)

The main difference being that I want to pass in arguments to the closure as well. Say I have something like this:

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(completionClosure: (venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError) -> ()) {
        // function body goes here
        var error: NSError?
        let responseDictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["test" : "test2"]
        completionClosure(venues: responseDictionary, error: error!)
    }
```

No error here. But when I call this function in my main view controller I have tried several ways but all of the result in different errors:

```
venueService.someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(completionClosure(venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError){

        })
```

or like this:

```
venueService.someFunctionThatTakesAClosure((venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError){

        })
```

or even like this:

```
venueService.someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(completionClosure: (venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError) -> (){

            });
```

I'm probably just way tired, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should give the exact text of the errors you got.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
venueService.someFunctionThatTakesAClosure({
  venues, error in
  // do stuff
})
```

you can optionally specify the types (but since the compiler knows what types the closure is supposed to provide, you don't strictly have to:

```
venueService.someFunctionThatTakesAClosure({
  (venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError) -> () in
  // do stuff
})
```

But I see another issue in your calling code:

```
completionClosure(venues: responseDictionary, error: error!)
//            No Bueno. What if there's no error?    ^^^^^^
```

You shouldn't force unwrap the error since it's entirely possible that it's still nil. Force unwrapping nil will cause an error. So you want this:

```
completionClosure(venues: responseDictionary, error: error)
```

AND you want to change your closure to take an optional error. In total:

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(completionClosure: (venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    …
    completionClosure(venues: responseDictionary, error: error)
}

// when calling:
venueService.someFunctionThatTakesAClosure({
  (venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError?) -> () in
  // do stuff
})
```

If you'd like to pass additional arguments, keep in mind swift is optimized for closures to be passed as the last argument (and it's a widely followed convention in objective-c APIs):

```
// in venueService:
func someArgAndClosureFunction(arg1: String, arg2: Int, 
                  completionClosure: (venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    // do stuff
}

// When calling:
venueService.someArgAndClosureFunction("string arg 1", arg2: 10) {
  (venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError?) -> () in
  // do stuff
}
```

In this example I've used the [trailing closure syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_126) which allows you pass the closure **outside** the function call parens (but it is still passed as the last argument).

Comment: Actually, in you second code block, I had to remove 'completionClosure:' in order for it to work.

Comment: Also, Say I want to pass in more arguments than just the closure. Is this possible? If so I'd really appreciate it if you could update your answer and show me. I just got errors when I tried.

Comment: @Nilzone- fixed bugs, added a multi-args example :)

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question: In you last codeblock when calling the function, you write the string directly, but in the second argument you specify "arg2:". Why? I get error if I also try to write "arg1:" in front of the string. I also get error if I remove "arg2:" from the second argument

Comment: @Nilzone- with method calls (by default, it's overridable) you don't need to name the first one, but you need to name all subsequent args. This is done for objective-c compatibility I think: `[myobject doStuffToColor:color opacity:opacity]` becomes `myobject.doStuffToColor(color, opacity: opacity)` - the method name acts like the first part of the obj-c message send

Answer (score 2):

I think you were probably just tired  :)

You're saying that the difficulty you are having is in calling the method, right? None of the examples you gave are passing a valid argument, which should be a closure of type:

`(Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, NSError) -> ()`

So there are a couple of things you could do...

(a) assign a conforming closure to a variable and pass the variable as the argument to the method:

```
let myClosure: (Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, NSError?) -> () = { venues, error in
    for (key, _) in venues {
        println(key)
    }
}

venueService.someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(myClosure)
```

(b) pass a trailing closure as the argument to the method call:

```
venueService.someFunctionThatTakesAClosure {
    venues, error in
    for (key, _) in venues {
        println(key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your error is optional, I would make it an optional argument of the passed function:

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(completionClosure: (venues: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
  // function body goes here
  var error: NSError? = nil
  let responseDictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["test" : "test2"]
  completionClosure(venues: responseDictionary, error: error)
}
```

It can then be invoked, passing a closure as follows:

```
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure { println($0); println($1) }
```

Note, the above is one of the shorthand syntax variants for creating closures.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for passing in parameters to closures revolve around the `in` keyword.

Sorry for the link url...but check out http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com/ and notice in the options where `in` appears.

see `array.sort({ (item1, item2) in return item1 < item2 })`

Which takes in `item1` and `item2` as 2 inputs