# How to handle a NSDictionary as a return type in iOS swift?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to convert and existing, working objective c application over to swift and I'm getting a little tripped up with "closures". Here's the old working objective c block that makes returns a value from a web service:

```
- (IBAction)didTapSayHiButton {
    [self.meteor callMethodName:@"sayHelloTo" parameters:@[self.username.text] responseCallback:^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *message = response[@"result"];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Meteor Todos" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Great" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }];
}
```

So here I'm getting either getting back a dictionary or response. And it works. 
And here's how I'm trying to go about this with swift (the method is slightly different):

```
@IBAction func sayHi(sender : AnyObject) {
    var params = [
        "name": "Scotty"
    ]
    meteor.callMethodName("sayHi", parameters: params, responseCallback: {
        (response: Dictionary<String, String>, error: NSError) in
        println("the name recieved back is: \(response)")
    })
}
```

The error I'm getting in xCode: "NSDictionary is not a subtype of 'Dictionary'"

[image]
After looking through the swift book this is the best educated attempt that I can make. I've tried a few other things but each resulted in another type of error.

How do I make this work with swift?

*Edit:* I've also tried just using `Dictionary` and `Dictionary<String, String>`

I should also note that I'm using a bridging header to access objective c code (objectiveDDP). And that `callMethodNamed` is written in objective c as can be seen here: https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP/blob/master/ObjectiveDDP/MeteorClient.h#L47

*Update:* by changing the method to:

`meteor.callMethodName("sayHi", parameters:["scotty"] , responseCallback:nil)`

we were able to get it to work. But the second we try to add in the closure, it starts throwing the same original errors.

Comment: Have you tried replacing Dictionary<String, Int> with NSDictionary?

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, I also tried Dictionary<String, String>. I'm pretty sure that in swift the types have to be explicitly declared unless they can be easily implied. I could be wrong though

Answer (score 1):

Try changing from using a Swift dictionary to explicitly using NSDictionary:

```
 @IBAction func sayHi(sender : AnyObject) {
    var params: NSDictionary = [
        "name": "Scotty"
    ]
    meteor.callMethodName("sayHi", parameters: params, responseCallback: {
        (response: NSDictionary!, error: NSError) in
        println("the name recieved back is: \(response)")
        })
}
```

Comment: Just tried that. It's pretty much the same error: "'NSDictionary!' is not a subtype of 'NSDictionary'"

Comment: It looks like it may be expecting an implicitly unwrapped optional of NSDictionary. Have you tried with the ! ?

Comment: I just tried add a ! to the end of NSDictionary and that seemed to clear up the error. But then I got a similar error for NSError so add a ! on to the end of that and that resulted in another error: Cannot convert the expression's type String! to type String!. Not sure where that's coming from.

Comment: Where is that coming from? The println?

Comment: No, it just an error in xCode that pops up the second I type it in

Comment: So it still appears with the println removed? How is your callMethodName declared?

Comment: I'm actually using a Bridging Header to access objective c code. Here's the method https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP/blob/master/ObjectiveDDP/MeteorClient.h#L47

Comment: what if the responseCallback is nil?

Comment: I'm not sure.. haven't run into any issues with that yet with the objective c. Is that why xCode is complaining?

Comment: I just want to see if the error is with your closure or another parameter. Does setting responsCallback to nil clear the error?

Comment: Oh ok, `meteor.callMethodName("sayHi", parameters: params, responseCallback: nil)` results in the "Cannot convert the expressions type String! to String!"

Comment: it may not like your first argument then? What if that one is set to nil?

Comment: Ok, I got it to compile by changing `parameters: params` to `parameters: ["scotty"]`. I've also verified that my web service is receiving the call. But I still can't get the closure to work as expected. It's obvious from the objective c that it's return a NSDictionary. Maybe it needs to somehow be casted to that type

Comment: is it just not printing?

Comment: No, as soon as I add a closure in there, we're right back to square one.. Same type of "subtype" errors

Comment: I'm thinking it's an issue with NSError. Try using NSErrorPointer instead

Comment: It's still not liking that. `NSError is not a subtype of NSErrorPoint!`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57232/discussion-between-connor-and-scotty).

Answer (score 0):

The trick, in this particular case, is to completely omit the closure's parameter types, and let the compiler figure it out. After searching around for a while, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129112/usage-of-closures-with-multiple-arguments-in-swift) which led me to the solution.

```
    meteor.callMethodName("sayHi", parameters:["scotty"] , responseCallback: {
        response, error in
        let me:String = response["result"] as String!
        println("called back \(me)")
    })
```

If your not worried about accessing the closures parameters, apparently you can also using an underscore to ignore them completely:

```
    meteor.callMethodName("sayHi", parameters:["scotty"] , responseCallback: {
        _ in
        // Do something here
    })
```